# Raster from postgis to image

Tags: node.js, angular, postgresql, image, express

I'm using **PostgreSQL 11** with **PostGIS 2.5.0** in **Windows 7 64-bits** and I'm learning full-stack development, the problem I've is I need to show an image in my web page but this image comes from a `STRING` in a `JSON` (`rid: int, raster: string, filename: string`), this STRING is a satelital image (`.TIF`), so there is a way to transform this string into a image again?.

I know there is a module for nodejs for transforming `base64` into images and save the image localy but I don't really need that (also don't know if will work).

Comment: Why are you not using geoserver for publishing your satellite image ??

Comment: Because I can't use it, I need to get the img directly from postgresql, is part of the requirements.